# Unable to attach HTMLTidy dll (libtidy.dll) to Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, htmltidy

Without much luck I've been trying to attach the HTMLTidy c++ library dll within Visual Studio, however everytime I get various errors with different builds.  I'm adding a reference to the project and then manually selecting the dll, which has been copied into a lib folder within the project folder.

The first dll I tried was from  Mark Beaton, and I'm using his HTMLTidy wrapper as it seems the most up to date.  The standard Win32 one was built.

[Mark Beaton Builds](https://github.com/markbeaton/TidyManaged/downloads)

I've also tried the build from the official HTMLTidy page, again the dll

[Official Build](http://www.paehl.com/open_source/?HTML_Tidy_for_Windows)

The error when referencing, please help!  I've tried compiling from source, but the source doesn't seem compatible with VS 2010.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

libtidy.dll is an unmanaged C DLL, so you can't add a reference to it in Visual Studio's Add Reference dialog. You need to build the C# code from https://github.com/markbeaton/TidyManaged into a managed DLL, and add a reference to that DLL instead.

Make sure that libtidy.dll is copied to your output folder; you can achieve this by adding the DLL file to your project, and changing its properties to "Copy to Output".

Comment: Can you explain this? I am having the same problem. I downloaded the TidyManaged project from git. Then I added libtidy.dll into this project and changed its property "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer" and compiled the project. Now, libtidy.dll exists in TidyManaged/bin/Debug directory. I added reference to TidyManaged.dll to my other project but with same error still.